# progress bar in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, progress-bar

I need a progress bar in a for loop in javascript

```js
for(index=0; index < 1000; index++){
    // set progress bar value to  index/1000 * 100 + '%'
}
```

I notice we can put it in a `setInterval` function, but it will cost more time to run the for loop.

So is there any way to run the for loop and generate the progress bar without cost more time?

Comment: you need that time added by a setinterval. running a loop 1000 times is so quick you won't see the progress bar actually progress...

Comment: @Bartdude what if the loop take more than half a miniute? Then it make sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So is there any way to run the for loop and generate the progress bar without cost more time?

Mostly no (see below for why "mostly"), you have to yield back to the browser (e.g., via `setTimeout` or `setInterval`) so it can update the page display, and that will indeed increase the amount of time the loop runs. Now, typically if you use a timeout of `0`, browsers will call you back in between 5 and 10 milliseconds. So call it 10ms. In your 1,000-cycle loop, you might yield every 100 cycles (e.g., 10 progress updates), which would only add 100ms or so to the total time.

FWIW, that looks like this (let's say it's an array you're looping through):

```
function loop(array, batchSize, callback) {
    var index = 0;

    doWork();

    function doWork() {
        var limit = Math.min(array.length, index + batchSize);
        while (index < limit) {
            // Do something with array[index]
        }
        if (limit < max) {
            setTimeout(doWork, 0);
        }
        else {
            callback(); // Done
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
loop(someArray, 100, function() {
    // Done
});
```

---

Why "mostly" no: On [some browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers) (not, notably, IE9 or earlier), for some tasks, you could use [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/). A web worker is an isolated JavaScript thread, separate from the main JavaScript thread, which runs in the background. The two threads communicate by posting messages to each other.

So you could fire up a web worker, hand it the work, and have it post you messages to update your progress bar. [This article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) gives the basics of web workers, if you want to go that route.

For what it's worth, it looks something like this:

Main document and script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Progress</title>
<style type="text/css">
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="progress"><em>(Click to start)</em></div>
<script>
(function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("progress");
  var counter = new Worker("counter.js");

  div.addEventListener("click", run);

  counter.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    div.innerHTML = "Counter so far: " + event.data.counter;
  });

  function run() {
    div.removeEventListener("click", run);
    counter.postMessage({ max: 10000000 });
  }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`counter.js` web-worker script (they're always separate files):

```
self.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  var max;
  var counter;

  max = event.data && event.data.max || 100000;
  for (counter = 0; counter < max; ++counter) {
    if (counter % 1000 === 0) {
      self.postMessage({counter: counter});
    }
  }
  self.postMessage({counter: counter});
});
```

Comment: But there are several example such as upload files, actuall it generates the progress bar exactly the time it needs.

Comment: @Kimmi: You'll find that those are typically Flash, not JavaScript.

Comment: @Kimmi: FWIW, I've added a second example, doing this sort of thing with a web worker instead.

Comment: the second example doesn't work. Chrome says: `Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18 `

Comment: @Kimmi: Yes, it does. Copy and paste exactly what's above, put them on a web server, and it works just fine. The HTML and the web worker's JavaScript file must be on the [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (but why wouldn't they be?). *Edit*: Ah, you're not trying to do this with local files (`file://` URLs), are you? A lot of things don't work correctly when you do that. Use an actual web server. Most browsers don't allow even two files from the same `file://` URL to work together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await and Promise + setTimeout as below
Plaese remember that in case You would like receive return value You have to use the **await iterate()** (from async function or console)

```js
document.body.innerHTML="<div id='id'>test</div>"
iterate()
    async function iterate() {

        function delay(ms=0000,foo=null) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve((foo && foo()));
                }, ms); // 5 sekund
            });
        }


        for (i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            await delay(0);
            document.getElementById("id").innerText=i;
        }
        return "END"
    }
```