# Pausing script execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to pause a script in the middle of it executing, how do i accomplish this without sticking it into a setTimeout? The problem is that this is just a snippet of code, the  rest is A LOT larger and it could get confusing by sticking it into the setTimeout.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: rAction,
    data: rData,
    success: function(msg){

    // BEFORE PROCEEDING TO THE FOLLOWING CODE, WAIT 5 SECONDS
    wait(5000); //?

    $('h1').hide();

    $('#result').html(msg);
    $('#alertTxt').html($('#result .system-error-message').html());
    $('#alert').slideDown('fast');
    $('#regForm').slideUp('fast');
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 170 }, 600);
    $('#but_submit').show();
    $('#processing').hide();

});
```

Comment: i would give your success function a name and move it out of the ajax command. you then breakup sections of code inside the function into more named functions. you can then easily call those sub-sections from one-another, using setTimeout if/as needed. the outer function provides a pseudo-global variable namepsace, which combined with closure from the sub-functions, makes it easy to manage state across an async flow without the complex nesting typically associated with callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code you want to delay in another function, then pass that function to setTimeout. This should keep your "real" code nice and tidy.

```
function handleResponse() {
  $('h1').hide();

  $('#result').html(msg);
  $('#alertTxt').html($('#result .system-error-message').html());
  $('#alert').slideDown('fast');
  $('#regForm').slideUp('fast');
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 170 }, 600);
  $('#but_submit').show();
  $('#processing').hide();
}

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: rAction,
  data: rData,
  success: function(msg){

  // BEFORE PROCEEDING TO THE FOLLOWING CODE, WAIT 5 SECONDS
  setTimeout(function() {
    handleResponse(msg);
  }, 5000); 
});
```

Comment: there's a lot of variables that need to be passed... and, after that function is finished, it has to fire off more of the script and pass the variables... gets very convoluted.

Comment: breaking your code into shorter functions will make it easier to keep track of things. also keep in mind that javascript is single-threaded so you shouldn't just stop the browser for 5s.

Comment: @Damien single-threaded, as in it only runs in a single thread. If the code processing is stopped, the browser will appear to be broken/unresponsive until it is started again. There are ways of causing this to happen, however if it is stopped for too long the browser will notify the user that the page is unresponsive and offer them the option of closing it (and it creates a poor user experience)

Comment: Had to go with this. Thanks

Comment: @Damien: *"there's a lot of variables that need to be passed"* Break your current function up into parts, but make those parts functions *within* the current function, and use the current function's variables. The functions within the function have access to those variables, you don't have to pass them around. More: *[Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)*

Answer (score 0):

> ...how do i accomplish this without sticking it into a setTimeout?

You can use [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) for long-running, complex code where you don't want to yield back to the browser. That code can't directly modify the DOM, but it can post messages back to the main script telling the main script what to change.

On browsers that don't support web workers, you basically have no choice but to yield back (`setTimeout` and its cousins).

You can find various web worker examples on the web, but for what it's worth, here's one I did [for another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17552517/157247), which just shows the progress of counting to a large number. But the concept is the same: A long-running script runs separately from the main JavaScript thread and posts updates to it via `postMessage`.

Main document and script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Progress</title>
<style type="text/css">
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="progress"><em>(Click to start)</em></div>
<script>
(function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("progress");
  var counter = new Worker("counter.js");

  div.addEventListener("click", run);

  counter.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    div.innerHTML = "Counter so far: " + event.data.counter;
  });

  function run() {
    div.removeEventListener("click", run);
    counter.postMessage({ max: 10000000 });
  }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`counter.js` web-worker script (they're always separate files):

```
self.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  var max;
  var counter;

  max = event.data && event.data.max || 100000;
  for (counter = 0; counter < max; ++counter) {
    if (counter % 1000 === 0) {
      self.postMessage({counter: counter});
    }
  }
  self.postMessage({counter: counter});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not put it in a function and call that function with setTimeout(func, 5000)?

Comment: More than half of the text of the question is *saying* why not.

Comment: I don't really see the difference between putting it into the $.ajax() function, or in a different function. Not less confusing imho.