# Instant updating UI elements using javascript

Tags: javascript

I know maybe this is not possible. 
I have searched the web but without suceess

I have a while loop and I want to do two things:

1. Update a textarea with formatted information
2. Update the width of div (a progress bar).

The first function has 4-5 additional sub-functions.

Basically I have a 6 elements numerical array. I have a custom format function to create a formatted string elements for my numbers. etc.

```
if (reg_index/reg_total > last_refresh) {    
    window.setTimeout ( 
        function() {
            document.getElementById("progress_line").style.width = "" + 100 * last_refresh + "px";
            document.getElementById("progress_value").innerHTML = my_format( 100*last_refreh, "###" ) + "%"; 
        },

        5
    );

    last_refresh+=0.01; 
}
```

Ok, I'm unable to define a right timeout interval to get what I want.

Can anybody point me to a useful link?

Thanks.

Comment: ...and the question is?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having here is that **all** of your functions will use the last value of `last_refresh`. When you define a function, it has an enduring reference to the variables in scope, not a *copy* of their values when it's created. More: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

You could do this:

```
function update() {
    if (reg_index/reg_total>last_refresh) 
        document.getElementById("progress_line").style.width =" "+100*last_refresh+"px";
        document.getElementById("progress_value").innerHTML=my_format(100*last_refreh,"###")+"%"; 
        last_refresh+=0.01; 
        setTimeout(update, 0); // Or 5 or whatever
    }
}
update();
```

That uses a function that does a bit of the work, then schedules itself to do more of the work in a moment. It closes over the `reg_index`, `reg_total`, and `last_refresh` variables.

If you know it needs to run at least once, you can make it slightly more efficient:

```
function update() {
    document.getElementById("progress_line").style.width =" "+100*last_refresh+"px";
    document.getElementById("progress_value").innerHTML=my_format(100*last_refreh,"###")+"%"; 
    last_refresh+=0.01; 
    if (reg_index/reg_total>last_refresh) 
        setTimeout(update, 0); // Or 5 or whatever
    }
}
update();
```

---

To help with the concept of looping with `setTimeout`, compare this standard loop (the browser doesn't update until the very end): [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ihujog/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ihujog/1/edit)

```
var a = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
var index;

for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
    display("Entry " + index + " is " + a[index]);
}
```

...with this equivalent using `setTimeout`, which yields to the browser on every iteration so it can update (and even if the interval is `0`, it runs much more slowly — I've used `200` here so you can see it run): [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ihujog/3) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ihujog/3/edit)

```
var a = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
var index;

index = 0;
update();
function update() {
    display("Entry " + index + " is " + a[index]);
    ++index;
    if (index < a.length) {
        setTimeout(update, 200);
    }
}
```

---

Below you've said:

> Unfortanetly I cant apply at my example.... I have a main loop with 2000 reads on local database.... I have done it works using timeouts but now my code spends a lot of time

I usually deal with that by breaking things up in to chunks (or see below for another alternative), example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ihujog/6) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ihujog/6/edit)

```
var index;
var total = 10000; // 10,000 to do in total

index = 0;
update();
function update() {
    var limit = Math.min(index + 100, total); // Do them 100 at at time
    while (index < limit) {
        if (index % 10 == 0) {
            display("Process entry #" + index);
        }
        ++index;
    }
    if (limit < total) {
        setTimeout(update, 200);
    }
}
```

Choose the size of the chunks so that you're updating (yield) often enough, but not updating (yielding) so much that you lose too much time. The above does it based on the number of loops, but another way is to let yourself run for (say) one full second and then yield. You can get a lot of work done in a second.

The other alternative is to use web workers, at least on [the browsers that support them](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers). [My other answer here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17552517/157247) has a discussion and example.

Even if you use web workers, though, you'll probably want to break the work into chunks, because if you have 2,000 records to get through, it doesn't make sense to update the progress bar 2,000 times &mdasdh; you'll just do updates a human can't readily perceive. 100 updates would be *more* than enough, probably even just 20 (so, 100 records/chunk) would be fine.

Comment: Thank Tj. My last_refresh var is defined outside the while loop, so it has the right value. In addittion I dont understad your code... Into a while {} where have I to write the update() calling? setTimeout calls the function once time , isn't ? Uff I dont undertstand this javascript behaviour... Thanks.

Comment: @tonnot: I've replaces the `while` loop by having the function call itself if it's not done. So (looking at the second code snippet above) we call `update`, it does an update, adds `0.01` to `last_refresh`, and then if `reg_index/reg_total>last_refresh` it schedules a call back to itself almost immediately using `setTimeout`. That "yields" to the browser allowing it to show the changes you've made. Then the timeout expires and the browser calls the function again. It does another update and, if there's still more to do, schedules itself again.

Comment: Thanks T.J.  mmmm I keep on confused.... I have the while () {} with a code that navigates trought an array and calculates some statistics. Remember I have to update the progressbar (for example every 5%) and also a textarea I fill line by line (and I have code to show the last line) . So, where I put the udate function definition and its calling ? Excuse me for being so persistent.. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @tonnot: You just put it where your current loop is. If you have a loop counter you haven't shown (for instance, to look through array elements), just put it in and increment it in the function. I've put a simplified example with live copies in the answer, showing first the normal loop (a `for` loop in my case), and then the `setTimeout` equivalent. Hope that helps. :-)

Comment: Ok, I understand. Unfortanetly I cant apply at my example.... I have a main loop with 2000 reads on local database.... I have done it works using timeouts but now my code spends a lot of time .... any other idea ? Trick ? Thanks for your time !

Comment: @tonnot: Usually in that situation I do chunks. I've added another example.